# What all jars are required for Spring + jersey

Tags: spring, jersey, version

I am wondering what all jars do I require to make Spring + Jersey work.

right now I had put the following jars in my buldpath.

```
Jersey-server-1.18
Spring 4.0.6
```

But my application does not seem to be working. what shall I use instead to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Jersey Spring DI support you will need to add the jersey-spring3 module. This is configuration and corresponding jars from my test project. Few of them may be optional.

Maven:

```
<dependencies>

    <!-- Jersey -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>2.11</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>
                    jersey-container-servlet-core
                </artifactId>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hk2</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- Spring 4 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Jars:

```
jersey-spring3-2.11.jar
spring-bridge-2.3.0-b05.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar
jsr250-api-1.0.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
spring-expression-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar
aspectjweaver-1.8.1.jar
```

Comment: Hi, I am not really using maven (any pom.xml). I am manually downloading the jars from the net and putting them in lib folder. Can you tell me what all jars will I require?

Comment: If I put the jars that I already have, plus the jersey-spring bundle also, will it work?

Comment: oki I have checked in my maven dependency folder and updated the answer

Comment: few of them may be optional e.g. javax annotations.

Comment: The simplest thing you can do is to open eclipse start new maven project copy dependencies from my post. Install and copy jars from dependencies folder to your project.